# How to take in input and show an mxml file in java

Tags: java, input, mxml

I wrote this simple code but i can't understand why it keeps returning me errors,
Can you help me?

```
{
/*XesXmlParser parser = new XesXmlParser();*/
XMxmlParser parser = new XMxmlParser();
InputStream is = null;

try {
    is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\examplefolder\\prova1.mxml");
    parser.parse(is);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
java.util.List<XLog> list = parser.parse(is);
System.out.println(list);


}
```

it gives me this error:

```
{Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
...
at org.deckfour.xes.in.XMxmlParser.parse(XMxmlParser.java:196)
at provaletturalog.LeggiLog.main(LeggiLog.java:26)
```

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: Which `parse` is it where you get this error? The second one, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `parser.parse(is)` call is causing the error because the stream has already been consumed by the previous method call.

So you need something like this:

```
XMxmlParser parser = new XMxmlParser();
List<XLog> list = Collections.emptyList();
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\examplefolder\\prova1.mxml")) {
    list = parser.parse(is);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(list);
```

I've used [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construction as streams should be closed to avoid leaks.